# How to create a docker private registry in EC2 Instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I would like to know **how to create a docker private registry in EC2 Instance?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating Docker-Machine with Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426933/integrating-docker-machine-with-amazon-ec2)

Comment: Yes and it is really helpful.

Comment: May i know what is wrong with this post to close this post?

Comment: The question was closed as duplicate and also is easy to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using managed solutions for docker registry to ensure scalability and availability like [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/), [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) or [Quay.io](https://quay.io/)

However, if you still want to have your own private registry in EC2, here are the steps for the simplest setup:

1. [Install](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/) docker inside the EC2. If you use AWS Linux AMI then docker is already installed.
2. Create a local directory to persist registry data

```
mkdir -p /opt/registry
```

3. Run the following command to spin up a private registry

```
docker run -d \
    -p 5000:5000 \
    --restart=always \
    --name registry \
    -v /opt/registry:/var/lib/registry \
    registry:2
```

4. Update the security group for EC2 so that the registry can be accessed from outside at port `5000`

Reference: [Docker documentations](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

**Note**: There are a lot of things to consider before bringing your private registry to production like: security (encrypting traffic at rest and in transit), high-availability (what if the EC2 is being shut-down for any reason), etc.

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: I tried and it worked for me.